# TypeScript is only looking node_modues and not trying to resolve aliased paths

Tags: typescript, webpack

In my `webpack.config.js` I created some aliases and I am trying to match these in my TypeScript configuration.

While running `--traceResolution` I noticed that it is just attempting to resolve these aliases imports as node_modules over and over.

```
// import Component from the aliased 'module'
import Component from 'somealias/component';

Would output something like:

Loading module 'somealias/component' from node_modules folder.
File '/.../.../node_modules/somealias/component' does not exist
File '/../node_modules/somealias/component' does not exist
File '/node_modules/somealias/component' does not exist
...
```

But what I would like it to do is to convert the 'somealias' alias into the correct path that I created in the tsconfig file.

My `tsconfig.json` file looks something like this:

```
{
  compilerOptions: {
    module: es6,
    moduleResolution: "node",
    target: es6,
    jsx: react,
  },

  typeRoots: [ "./path/to/typingsfolder" ],
  baseUrl: ".",
  paths: {
    "somealias/*": [
      "path/to/resolve/to/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: is `module/component` a file path, or the name of a module?  Typically you'd do `import {ModuleName} from "modulename"` or `import {ModuleName} from "./path/to/file"`.  When you don't do a file path (meaning it starts with `./` or `../` or whatever), it will look to node_modules based on your tsconfig.  This may be helpful:  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: I made a mistake. I meant to show that I was trying to import from the alias I created in the `paths` option: `somealias`.